# Making shifted hyper super

Tags: xkb

I have the Happy Hacking keyboard, which only has one pair of extra
modifiers in addition to ctrl and meta.  I want to use these for super
and hyper, and I don't want one for super and the other for hyper.  An
ideal solution would be to make hyper the default, which would be
useful in Emacs, and make a shifted hyper turn into a super.  Thus,
for instance, super+shift would be produced by: pressing shift,
pressing hyper, releasing shift, pressing shift.  Ideally, shift+hyper
should immediately forget the shift, so that shift+super were also
produced by: pressing lshift, pressing hyper, pressing rshift.
hyper+shift would be produced by pressing hyper before shift.

I have tried to do this with xkb, but it is poorly documented and very
complicated.  One problem is that simply putting hyper on level 1 and
super on level 2 will by default produce hyper+super on level 1.  Is
there a way?

Comment: I also have an HHKB, and my ideal way is to program it onto the board itself using a Hasu controller (https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=71517.0).  A little involved, but that way it's actually programmed into the board and not reliant on the OS.

Comment: @bgregs, looks like fun but time-consuming.  Can you do what I want with that?

Comment: I have used it on a previous board for remapping two key presses to a single action (section 2.1.2 in docs).  Basically the board becomes completely programmable (seriously, you can even map mouse events to the keys).  Here's the Hasu helpful key editor (or you can do it by hand): http://www.tmk-kbd.com/tmk_keyboard/editor/unimap/?hhkb
Here's the docs: https://github.com/tmk/tmk_keyboard/blob/master/tmk_core/doc/keymap.md#41-tap-key